# innerHTML not changing div output

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display a text area depending on what radio button the user clicks. When the "contest" function is commented out, the newsletter part works fine. But when the contest function is included, the newsletter does not work. I've tried debugging but I can't seem to find an issue. I've tried using different forms but it doesn't change the problem.

My HTML:

```js
function newsletter() {
 var response = "";
 if(document.getElementById("yes").checked) {

  response += "<p><b>Enter Your Address:</b></p>";
  response += '<input type="text" id="address"><br>';

  var output = document.getElementById("isChecked");
  output.innerHTML = response;
 }
} 

function contest() {
 var resp = "";
 if(document.getElementById("answer").value == "Y") {
  resp += "<p><b>Enter your credit card information to verify age ($0.00 charge)</b></p>";
  resp += "<br>";
  resp += '<input type="text" id="first4" size="4" maxlength="4">';
  resp += "-";
  resp += '<input type="text" id="second4" size="4" maxlength="4">';
  resp += "-";
  resp += '<input type="text" id="third4" size="4" maxlength="4">';  
  resp += "-";
  resp += '<input type="text" id="fourth4" size="4" maxlength="4"';

  var out = document.getElementById("contestOutput");
  out.innerHTML = resp;
 }
}
```

```css
body {background-color: pink; }
```

```html
  <center>
   <h1>Magnificant Music!</h1>
  </center>
  <p>Welcome Blue Note Records visitors! On this site, you can enter your information to recieve a card sent every month informing you about the lastest releases on your favorite record label, and a chance to enter a contest that could win you a brand new instrument of your choice!</p>
  <form action="" method="post">
   <fieldset>
    <p><b>Personal Information</b></p>
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName"><br>
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastName"><br>
    <label>Middle Initial</label>
    <input type="text" id="middleInit"><br>
   </fieldset>
   <br>
   <fieldset>
    <p><b>Do you want to recieve a newsletter?</b></p>
    <input type="radio" name="news" id="yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="news" id="no">No<br>
    <button type="button" onclick="newsletter();">Submit</button>
    <div id="isChecked"></div>
   </fieldset>
   <br>
   <fieldset>
    <p><b>Would you like to enter the contest for a brand new instrument of your choice (Y / N)? (18 yrs old minimum)</b></p>
    <input type="text" size="1" id="answer"><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="contest();">Submit</button>
    <div id="contestOutput"></div>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: Any errors u see in the console of your browser?

Comment: You didn't closed last input in `contest` function.

Comment: It may help you in the future to use a text editor, IDE, or something like [JSHint](https://jshint.com/) that surfaces those sorts of little syntax errors for you.

Comment: @benvc I don't think that jsHint will find html errors in strings.

Comment: @jcubic - you are absolutely right. I should have been more clear in my comment as I was reacting to a `:` line ending syntax issue that OP has already corrected in an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, provided by @jcubic, was the error. Closing the tag fixed the error encountered.

Comment: You're not out of the woods yet. Your HTML uses old, invalid tags and the approach you are taking should really be modernized. For example, the very error you had wouldn't have even happened if you built new DOM elements using the DOM API and not by building strings of HTML. Or, just have the element(s) the might need to be shown already built and in place, but just hidden with CSS. Then you just need the JavaScript to show the element(s), not to build them on the fly and inject them into the DOM.